# How to open downloads folder from Run after changing location?

Tags: windows-10, run-dialog

I am using Windows 10. When I am using Windows 8.1, I have changed my `Downloads` folder to `D:\Downloads`.

When I type `downloads` in Run, I get **Windows cannot find Downloads. Make sure you typed name correctly** error. But, when the downloads location, is its default, I am able to access it.

How to regain access to downloads from Run? I tried, setting the Downloads folder to its default, moving them and again back to `D:\Downloads`, then also it doesn't happen.

I would also like to have a solution, for Music, Videos folders.

Comment: You will need to edit your run PATH. Look here; *under Control panel system* 


http://etherealmind.com/putty-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment from @Tealkine, I have put a `Path` variable in the **Environment Variables** and put the value to `D:\`